Google Coud Run Job not integrating with Docker DinD: for build and push Docker images
What am I doing with cloud run job

I am trying to use cloud run job as self hosted runners for github
I wanted my runner to build and push docker images so I used DinD(Docker in Docker) Pattern as I cannot directly volume mount /var/run/docker.sock in cloud run job (Docker out of Docker)
so I build my own docker dind image for runner

build-self-hosted-runner: github
Dockerfile and other files
FROM ubuntu:22.04


# RUNNER ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES
ARG RUNNER_VERSION="2.316.0"

ENV GITHUB_PERSONAL_TOKEN ""
ENV GITHUB_OWNER ""
ENV GITHUB_REPOSITORY ""
ENV RUNNER_NAME ""
# END OF RUNNER ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES

RUN apt update \
    && apt install -y ca-certificates \
    wget curl iptables supervisor \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/list/* \
    && update-alternatives --set iptables /usr/sbin/iptables-legacy

ENV DOCKER_CHANNEL=stable \
    DOCKER_VERSION=26.0.1 \
    DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION=v2.26.1 \
    BUILDX_VERSION=v0.13.1 \
    DEBUG=false

# Docker and buildx installation
RUN set -eux; \
    \
    arch="$(uname -m)"; \
    case "$arch" in \
        # amd64
        x86_64) dockerArch='x86_64' ; buildx_arch='linux-amd64' ;; \
        # arm32v6
        armhf) dockerArch='armel' ; buildx_arch='linux-arm-v6' ;; \
        # arm32v7
        armv7) dockerArch='armhf' ; buildx_arch='linux-arm-v7' ;; \
        # arm64v8
        aarch64) dockerArch='aarch64' ; buildx_arch='linux-arm64' ;; \
        *) echo >&2 "error: unsupported architecture ($arch)"; exit 1 ;;\
    esac; \
    \
    if ! wget -O docker.tgz "https://download.docker.com/linux/static/${DOCKER_CHANNEL}/${dockerArch}/docker-${DOCKER_VERSION}.tgz"; then \
        echo >&2 "error: failed to download 'docker-${DOCKER_VERSION}' from '${DOCKER_CHANNEL}' for '${dockerArch}'"; \
        exit 1; \
    fi; \
    \
    tar --extract \
        --file docker.tgz \
        --strip-components 1 \
        --directory /usr/local/bin/ \
    ; \
    rm docker.tgz; \
    if ! wget -O docker-buildx "https://github.com/docker/buildx/releases/download/${BUILDX_VERSION}/buildx-${BUILDX_VERSION}.${buildx_arch}"; then \
        echo >&2 "error: failed to download 'buildx-${BUILDX_VERSION}.${buildx_arch}'"; \
        exit 1; \
    fi; \
    mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins; \
    chmod +x docker-buildx; \
    mv docker-buildx /usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx; \
    \
    dockerd --version; \
    docker --version; \
    docker buildx version

COPY modprobe start-docker.sh runner.sh entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
COPY supervisor/ /etc/supervisor/conf.d/
COPY logger.sh /opt/bash-utils/logger.sh

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start-docker.sh \
    /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh \
    /usr/local/bin/runner.sh \
    /usr/local/bin/modprobe

VOLUME /var/lib/docker

# Docker compose installation
RUN curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/${DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION}/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose && docker-compose version

# Create a symlink to the docker binary in /usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins
# for users which uses 'docker compose' instead of 'docker-compose'
RUN ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose





# Install the GitHub Actions Runner 
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y sudo jq

WORKDIR /actions-runner
RUN curl -Ls https://github.com/actions/runner/releases/download/v${RUNNER_VERSION}/actions-runner-linux-x64-${RUNNER_VERSION}.tar.gz | tar xz \
  && bash ./bin/installdependencies.sh

COPY entrypoint.sh /actions-runner/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /actions-runner/entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
# CMD ["bash"]

entrypoint.sh:
#!/bin/bash

# Start docker
start-docker.sh

bash -c runner.sh

start-docker.sh
#!/bin/bash
source /opt/bash-utils/logger.sh

function wait_for_process () {
    local max_time_wait=30
    local process_name="$1"
    local waited_sec=0
    while ! pgrep "$process_name" >/dev/null && ((waited_sec < max_time_wait)); do
        INFO "Process $process_name is not running yet. Retrying in 1 seconds"
        INFO "Waited $waited_sec seconds of $max_time_wait seconds"
        sleep 1
        ((waited_sec=waited_sec+1))
        if ((waited_sec >= max_time_wait)); then
            return 1
        fi
    done
    return 0
}

INFO "Starting supervisor"
/usr/bin/supervisord -n >> /dev/null 2>&1 &

INFO "Waiting for docker to be running"
wait_for_process dockerd
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    ERROR "dockerd is not running after max time"
    exit 1
else
    INFO "dockerd is running"
fi

runner.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Starting runner"
cd /actions-runner || exit 1

registration_url="https://api.github.com/orgs/${GITHUB_OWNER}/actions/runners/registration-token"
echo "Requesting registration URL at '${registration_url}'"

echo "Starting runner"
payload=$(curl -sX POST -H "Authorization: token ${GITHUB_PERSONAL_TOKEN}" ${registration_url})
export RUNNER_TOKEN=$(echo $payload | jq .token --raw-output)

RUNNER_CPU="2"
RUNNER_MEMORY="4GB"
RUNNER_NAME_ARGUMENT_PASSED=$RUNNER_NAME
RUNNER_NAME="quicksilver-${RUNNER_CPU}cpu-${RUNNER_MEMORY}"

if [ -n "$RUNNER_NAME_ARGUMENT_PASSED" ]; then
    RUNNER_NAME=$RUNNER_NAME_ARGUMENT_PASSED
fi

echo "RUNNER_NAME: ${RUNNER_NAME}"

random_string() {
    cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-z0-9' | fold -w 10 | head -n 1
}

RUNNER_ALLOW_RUNASROOT=1
export RUNNER_ALLOW_RUNASROOT=1

./config.sh \
    --name "${RUNNER_NAME}-$(random_string)" \
    --token ${RUNNER_TOKEN} \
    --labels ${RUNNER_NAME} \
    --url https://github.com/${GITHUB_OWNER} \
    --work "/work" \
    --unattended \
    --replace \
    --ephemeral

remove() {
    ./config.sh remove --token "${RUNNER_TOKEN}"
}

trap 'remove; exit 130' INT
trap 'remove; exit 143' TERM

./run.sh "$*" &

wait $!

remove
echo "Runner stopped."

inside supervisor/ folder there is single file dockerd.conf
dockerd.conf:
[program:dockerd]
command=/usr/local/bin/dockerd
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/dockerd.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/dockerd.out.log

logger.sh (can ignore: just logging functions)
#!/bin/sh
# Logger from this post http://www.cubicrace.com/2016/03/log-tracing-mechnism-for-shell-scripts.html

function INFO(){
    local function_name="${FUNCNAME[1]}"
    local msg="$1"
    timeAndDate=`date`
    echo "[$timeAndDate] [INFO] [${0}] $msg"
}


function DEBUG(){
    local function_name="${FUNCNAME[1]}"
    local msg="$1"
    timeAndDate=`date`
    echo "[$timeAndDate] [DEBUG] [${0}] $msg"
}

function ERROR(){
    local function_name="${FUNCNAME[1]}"
    local msg="$1"
    timeAndDate=`date`
    echo "[$timeAndDate] [ERROR]  $msg"
}

How I tested in local
docker run --privileged -e GITHUB_PERSONAL_TOKEN="<github-token>" -e GITHUB_OWNER="<org-name>" -e RUNNER_NAME="<runner-name-we-use-in-workflow>" docker-image-name

docker exec -it contianer-id bash

root@e321f2254280:/actions-runner# docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES

--privileged in above docker run command is important else dockerd will not run
What I tried to test and Error

I have tried to docker build a frontend(React) from build folder(npm run build)

Dockerfile for frontend:


FROM nginx:alpine
COPY build /usr/share/nginx/html/
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf


The above dockerfile is woking in cloud run

But (The Problem)
1.If I change the frontend Dockerfile to:
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
COPY build/ /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["nginx","-g","daemon off;"]


It throws error in cloud run

#6 [2/4] COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
#6 DONE 0.1s

time="2024-05-04T12:59:49.389187868Z" level=warning msg="Failed to delete conntrack state for 172.17.0.2: invalid argument"
#7 [3/4] RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

#7 0.289 runc run failed: unable to start container process: unable to apply caps: operation not permitted

time="2024-05-04T12:59:49.551708303Z" level=warning msg="Failed to delete conntrack state for 172.17.0.2: invalid argument"
#7 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1


------
 > [3/4] RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*:
0.289 runc run failed: unable to start container process: unable to apply caps: operation not permitted

------
Dockerfile:4
--------------------
   2 |     COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
   3 |     USER root
   4 | >>> RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
   5 |     COPY build/ /usr/share/nginx/html
   6 |     EXPOSE 80
--------------------

ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
21  /usr/local/bin/dockerd
github.com/moby/buildkit/executor/runcexecutor.exitError
    /go/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/moby/buildkit/executor/runcexecutor/executor.go:374


I understand I can just remove the RUN rm ...  will solve this problem but in future there is a high probability to use rm in Dockerfiles... and not only rm there are many restrictions that we cannot do in cloud run jobs.

Replicate Problem
test-self-runner: github
build-self-hosted-runner: github
Is this the right approach? am I missing something?

Are you able run RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/\* locally?  Can you try RUN rm -f /usr/share/nginx/html/\* or RUN rm /usr/share/nginx/html/\* ?

yes, in local when ran the container it was running perfectly

Have you tried without -rf or -r?

tried without -rf but same error: screenshot

for testing I have also tried adding RUN echo "file here" > file.txt : same error
